# Laravel 5.2 - middleware auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware

i just installed laravel 5.2,  and i created auth register, login, and reset password, but now i want create a index of my project where all user (also not logged) can access. i tryed to create

Route::get('/',HomeController@home');

But this view is enable only for users logged.

MY ROUTES

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
// POST - FORM CREA 
Route::get('/crea-regalo', 'PostController@form');
Route::post('/crea-regalo', 'PostController@creaPost');
// LISTA ANNUNCI PRINCIPALE
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');
```

MY HOME CONTROLLER

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('id','DESC');
        return view('home', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function home()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('index', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

How can i create routes of view where ALL users can access?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi write separate controller to access page to all because you have written auth middleware in contructor

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Similar like

```
class GuestController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }


    public function home()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('index', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

In route

```
Route::get('/home', 'GuestController@home');
```

or else you can do like this

```
$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['home']]);
```

this will able to access home page for all .In your constructor add this

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['home']]);
}
```

Comment: yup! thank you! i will create another controller, is the best choice!

Answer (score 2):

Put those route which you want to allow only authenticated user in middleware auth as follows:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
  //your routes    
})
```

And for those routes which all user can access put that out side the above group.